# Ubuntu lag, Mouse keyboard stuck, and screen blink every 5 seconds

Tags: 14.04

I just installed ubuntu in my Acer 4820TG yesterday but everything lag

every 5 seconds(approximately) my mouse keyboard stuck, screen blink, and loop

here is VDO https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AG-KJJ_DqI [in this vdo i circling my mouse , you will see my mouse stop every 5 seconds.]

PS: I tried to search in google about this problem in different keyword but all of my effort was to no avail.

Post from my laggy ubuntu

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /proc/meminfo`.